# Equivalent of constantize with ruby facet

Tags: ruby, facet

We are using ruby facets for a new project and I need the equivalet of the 'constantize' method.
I know I can require ActiveSupport for that, but I was wondering, is that something which Factes provides or do I need ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't answer the "is that something which Facets provides" part of your question, but it definitely answers the "or do I need ActiveSupport" one. It also shows you how that method actually is implemented, which is pretty straightforward

```
class String
  def constantize
    self.split("::").inject(Module) {|acc, val| acc.const_get(val)}
  end
end
```

**Edit:** For what it is worth, Facets has a `constant` method, see http://rubyworks.github.com/rubyfaux/?doc=http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/docs/facets-2.9.3/core.json#api-module-Kernel/api-method-Kernel-h-constant